# Using jQuery .append on individual elements in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, javascript-objects

Trying something new here and I'm having some trouble understanding why this isn't working as I intended.

So, I've set up a few elements with a simple for loop for simplicity sake:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    $('body').append('<div class="green">Here I am</div>');
}
```

And I have all of the items selected as an object (I'll be needing to change each item individually) as such:

```
$greenDivs = $('div.green');
```

Now, when I want to access it, I can do it just fine in the console by using its index:

```
console.log($greenDivs[3]);
```

which returns a nice, neat console of: `<div class="green">` which I can also see selected on the page.

However, when I try to alter it in any way with some jQuery functions, I just receive an error such as `$greenDivs[3].append is not a function`

Why aren't the functions working? Is it because of the way that the `.green` elements are being categorized into an object? I can use all of the basic JS properties like:

`$greenDivs[3].innerHTML = "Whatever"`

Any help is appreciated in understanding why I have to use the basic javascript object properties to modify individual elements.

Play here if you want an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/eacdtzjw/2/

Comment: $($greenDivs[3]).append('Hello'); works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$greenDivs[3]` gives you a DOM node. Those don't have any jQuery specific methods.

To keep it as a jQuery object, use `$greenDivs.eq(3)` (see https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

You can of course re-wrap it as a jQuery object, like `$( $greenDivs[3] )`, but that's an unnecessary step in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the element `$greenDivs[3]`:

```js
$(function(){
 for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
   $('body').append('<div class="green">Here I am</div>');
  }
  $greenDivs = $('div.green');
  console.log($greenDivs[3]);

   $($greenDivs[3]).append('Hello');

});
```

```css
.green {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

$greenDivs[3] actually is an object not an jquery object. If you want to use jquery append function you should

```
  $($greeenDivs[3]).append('...');
```

or

```
 $greenDivs.eq(3).append('....')
```